# subversive svn:externals reference to a fixed revision does not honor revision

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

an svn:externals reference like this

```
dojo -r 21434 http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/dojo/trunk/
```

is happily accepted by subversive in the set properties panel and the link is established. However, the revision is ignored.  Each time I upgrade, I get the latest from trunk.  It does not seem to matter whether or not I include a space between the -r and the number.  Is this the right syntax?  Is this a problem with subversive?

I'm using the Galileo release, subversive 0.7.8.I20090904-1300

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the form

```
-r 21434 http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/dojo/trunk/ dojo
```

instead of

```
dojo -r 21434 http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/dojo/trunk/
```

Comment: I upgraded to the 0.7.8.I2009-1023-1300 release, mostly to fix the problem where error messages were getting lost in an exception and lo and behold, the dialog for editing svn:properties actually spells out the correct syntax for this.  Note, I needed to also remove the space between the -r and the revision to make it work (i.e. -r21334)  With the space, it just ignored the -r switch and took the trunk without any warning.  Fail.  Surprising that both argument orders seemed to be honored.  I also seemed to need to check out a new workspace in order to get a valid update going.

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact answer on your question, but another way of achieving what you want:

Instead of adding an external, just copy the revision of the trunk into your current project.  Since you are referring to a fixed revision, you are not accepting changes on it.  Making a personal copy has the same effect, and copies don't take extra space in Subversion as long as you don't change them.

I you want to prevent someone making changes to your personal copy, mark it as read-only (you can do that in the Subversion configuration).

Comment: A reasonable workaround, but it makes it a bit harder to upgrade, which I'd want to do fairly often.